# MongoDB giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, mongodb, nullpointerexception, database

I have a problem in my code. I have a collection of objects in Mongo, all of which have a "name", "description", "imageURL", "code".

I want to do a search of my collection and return ArrayList of all the names, descriptions,codes and imageURLs

I tried it like this

```
else{
            DBCursor cursair = this.searchItem(code);
            while(cursair.hasNext()){
                this.searchNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                this.searchBarcodes = new ArrayList<String>();
                this.searchDescriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
                this.searchImageURLs = new ArrayList<String>();                 
                this.searchNames.add(cursair.curr().get(ITEMS_NAME).toString());
                this.searchDescriptions.add(cursair.curr().get(ITEMS_DESCRIPTION).toString());
                this.searchImageURLs.add(cursair.curr().get(ITEMS_IMAGEURL).toString());
                this.searchBarcodes.add(cursair.next().get(ITEMS_CODE).toString());
            }
```

I have a problem with it as it gives me a NullPointerException at`this.searchNames.add(cursair.curr().get(ITEMS_NAME).toString());`.
`ITEMS_NAME` is a String constant defined in the code.

the `searchItem(code)` method looks like this

```
public DBCursor searchItem(String searchQuery){

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put(ITEMS_NAME, java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(searchQuery));
    DBCursor cursor = itemsCollection.find(query);
    return cursor;
}
```

I also checked in my debugger, when I call `cursor.toArray()` it returns a `List<DBObject>` with a size of 5, so I am pretty confident about cursor having the right information in itself

Comment: Post the stack trace. As a note, it's much more difficult to debug statements that are that compound; there are four different items that could be `null` right there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the stack trace didn't give any useful information. Also the answer below helped me, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `cursair.next()` as the first step in your while loop and use the `DBObject` returned to extract your data.